# Google Webmaster Tools sitemap validation error: We were unable to read your Sitemap. It may contain an entry we are unable to recognize

Tags: xml, validation, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm getting an XML validation error on [this file](https://www.toptrouwen.nl/sitemap_nl11.xml) in my Google Webmaster Tools (it's too big to post here): `We were unable to read your Sitemap. It may contain an entry we are unable to recognize. Please validate your Sitemap before resubmitting.`

I checked the XML file through XML buddy desktop application, and tried several online XML validators (which can't handle files this large) and even went through it manually.
But all nodes seem to be defined fine, so I still can't find why Google Webmaster Tools does not validate this file.
The file is also under the limits set by Google: there are less than 50,000 URLs in it and the file is smaller than 10MB, so that should not be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to follow the link but my browser won't open the page.
Getting this message

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>
> Location: https://www.toptrouwen.nl/sitemap_nl11.xml
>
> Line Number 1, Column 5641744:

Try checking that column and see what is around there